# Unrecognized option: -n Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. in java

Tags: java

```
java -n -t F:\Test73\Jmeter\Software\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\LoadTest\navCorp.jmx -l F:\Test73\Jmeter\Software\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\LoadTest\loadTest.csv

Unrecognized option: -n

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: What do you think the `-n` option does? The `java` command has no `-n` option.

Comment: yeah You are right i was trying Jmeter but instead I used Java